# Adding Number of Subviews in ViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, view, addsubview

[image]

In this image when i press the Add view button, every time add new subview in the same viewcontroller and also delete button pressed subview also deleted.
Any one know can you help me friends.

Comment: Can you show us here  what you done so far to achieve this ?

Comment: one or two views added i tried before but my requirement is  user press the add view button every time one new subview is needed.

Comment: can you post that add view code so we can help you out here?

Comment: This view i am taking programatically, code is too big.

Comment: Is the superview where you want do add your subviews a scrollview or a tableview?

Comment: Every view added in scrollview.

Comment: Ok, but i think it would be easier to show the views in a tableview, but anyway i will give you an answer

Comment: Use Table Instead, add rows when required.

Answer (score 0):

What you have to do is to hold the subviews in an array.

Give the buttons (delete and add) the tag of the position in the array.

Then, when you click on "add view" or "delete" you will know where you have to insert or delete a subview in the array.

After that, set the button tags to the new indexes and then update your scrollview.

It would be easier in a tableview, because you don't have to calculate the content size and the positions in the scroll views

Answer (score 0):

I'll recommend you not to use UIViews tags at all, this is not maintainability.
So first lets start from you viewcontrollers class and add three properties there:

```
@property(nonatomic, strong) UIButton *deleteButton;
@property(nonatomic, strong) UIButton *addButton;
@property(nonatomic, strong) NSMutableArray *addedSubviews;
```

viewDidLoad method:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.deleteButton = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 40)];
    [self.view addSubview:self.deleteButton];
    [self.deleteButton addTarget:self action:@selector(onDeleteSubview) forControlEvents:(UIControlEventTouchUpInside)];

    self.addButton = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 40)];
    [self.view addSubview:self.addButton];
    [self.addButton addTarget:self action:@selector(onAddSubview) forControlEvents:(UIControlEventTouchUpInside)];

    self.addedSubviews = [NSMutableArray new];
}

- (void)onDeleteSubview {
     UIView *viewToDelete = [self.addedSubviews lastObject];
    [viewToDelete removeFromSuperview];
    [self.addedSubviews removeLastObject];
    [self.view layoutSubviews];
}

- (void)onAddSubview {
    UIView *desiredView = [UIView new]; // create view you need
    [self.view addSubview:desiredView];
    [self.addedSubviews addObject:desiredView];
    [self.view layoutSubviews];
}
```

Here we iterate over each view and layout them

```
- (void)viewWillLayoutSubviews {

    [super viewWillLayoutSubviews];

    float start_y_point = 0; //as you wish
    float padding = 10;

    [self.addedSubview enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(UIView *view, NSUInteger idx, BOOL * _Nonnull stop) {
        view.frame = CGRectMake({<#CGFloat x#>}, start_y_point + padding, {<#CGFloat width#>}, {<#CGFloat height#>})
        start_y_point += view.frame.size.height + padding;
    }];


}
```

Last thing is to place buttons

Comment: But why? Have you replaced all places within your needs?